# COUNT() without DISTINCT in multi LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

I have 3 tables

```
orders
-----------------
| id | order_data |
-----------------

codes
-----------------------------
| id | code_data | order_id |
-----------------------------

actions (please note, in the table the primary key doesn't exists)
--------------------------
| action_name | order_id |
--------------------------
```

How can I count the number of actions by order, if the actions rows have no unique value in table `actions`, and thus `DISTINCT` in `COUNT()` does not make sense.
My query:

```
SELECT `orders`.*, COUNT(DISTINCT `codes`.`id`), COUNT(`actions`.`action_name`) 
FROM `orders`
LEFT JOIN `codes` ON `codes`.`id` = `orders`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `actions` ON `actions`.`id` = `orders`.`id`
WHERE `actions`.`action_name` IN (/*some values*/)
GROUP BY `orders`.`id`
```

Comment: Why are you LEFT JOINing to actions when your WHERE clause renders the LEFT obsolete? What are codes, and how many are there per order? 'How can I count the number of actions by order, if the actions rows have no unique value in table actions, and thus DISTINCT in COUNT() does not make sense.' <- I'm having a hard time understanding this sentence

Comment: i think an inner join would help you.

Comment: Change WHERE to AND. @Arth I rather think that's the point of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count in the other tables before joining, like this:

```
SELECT
       `orders`.*
     , IFNULL(a.CountActs, 0) CountActs
     , IFNULL(c.CountCodes, 0) CountCodes
FROM `orders`
LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT `order_id`, count(*) CountCodes
             FROM `codes`
             GROUP BY `order_id`
            ) c ON `orders`.`id` = c.`order_id`
LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT `order_id`, count(*) CountActs
             FROM `actions`
             WHERE `actions`.`action_name` IN (/*some values*/)
             GROUP BY `order_id`
            ) a ON `orders`.`id` = a.`order_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT orders.*
     , COUNT(DISTINCT c.id)
     , COUNT(a.action_name) 
  FROM orders o
  LEFT 
  JOIN codes c
    ON c.id = o.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN actions a
    ON a.id = o.id
   AND a.action_name IN (/*some values*/)
 GROUP 
    BY o.id
```

Comment: Really need to be sure there can't be more than one code per order before you can assume this will work.

Comment: @Arth You're almost certainly right - but it depends on exactly what it is that the OP wants to count.

Comment: Ty, but COUNT(a.action_name) from your query returns the same wrong result, like in my query. I want count codes number, actions count and fetch orders witch have some action

Comment: @gutsout I suggest you provide proper DDLs (and an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT